Add column using DAX
I need to add a column using DAX (measure), I have  a table and I need to extract the first letter from anothor column.
I can't use trasform data to add the column



TEXT
LEFT




ABC
A


DFS
D



I've also tried the following:
LEFT = 
VAR __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[TEXT])
VAR __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW = 1
RETURN
    IF(
        __DISTINCT_VALUES_COUNT > __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
        CONCATENATE(
            CONCATENATEX(
                TOPN(
                    __MAX_VALUES_TO_SHOW,
                    VALUES('TABLE'[TEXT]),
                    LEFT('TABLE'[TEXT],1),
                    ASC
                ),
                LEFT('TABLE'[TEXT],1),
                ", ",
                LEFT('TABLE'[TEXT],1),
                ASC
            ),
            ",  ecc."
        ),
        CONCATENATEX(
            VALUES('TABLE'[TEXT]),
            LEFT('TABLE'[TEXT],1),
            ", ",
            LEFT('TABLE'[TEXT],1),
            ASC
        )
    )

But I don't know where I can add addcolumn.
If I use addcolumn in another formula I have scalar error

ADDCOLUMN is what we used in PQ. If you want to use DAX you can try this
Column = LEFT('Table'[TEXT],1)


If you want to do this in PQ, you can try this



Measure = left(max('Table'[TEXT]),1)



The problem is that I don't have PQ. I have page report and model, not the table

I have updated the answer, pls see the last part of it

I have an aggregation error

could you pls provide some sample data?

I can't because the data are in private datalake
